# How do you use the CLT without knowing variance?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, computational-statistics, central-limit-theorem

The Gompertz distribution has a mean that's difficult to calculate, a variance that is very difficult to calculate (has a hypergeometric function in it), and a skewness that I can't find anyone even talking about trying to calculate. So I can't use the berry-esseen theorem to quantify the error of the CLT approximation because I don't have the skew, and I can't apply the CLT without the variance. How can one proceed in cases like this, for example to apply the CLT to approximate the sum of 1000 Gompertz random variables, assuming you can't calculate the variance?

Comment: This particular hypergeometric function converges very rapidly and so, in effect, is even *easier* to compute than exponentials.  The moments involve incomplete Gamma functions (which are a staple of any statistical computing platform) and the "exponential integral" (which is an incomplete Gamma function of parameter 0). Indeed, the moment generating function is itself proportional to an incomplete Gamma, which means you could use it directly to obtain numerical estimates of moments.

Comment: So in general, you have to have at least an estimate of the variance to use the CLT, and at least an estimate of the skewness to estimate the error of the CLT? No way around that?

Can I at least find some way to compute a simpler *bound* on the skewness so I don't have to go through an incredible amount of error-prone mathematics?

Comment: It depends on how you want to "use" the CLT.  Do you know the parameters of your random variables or not?  Are they identically distributed or not?

Comment: Identically distributed random variables with known parameters; I want to get an approximation to the likelihood of the sum of these independent random variables with accuracy so good that I can use it in the middle of a Monte Carlo simulation

Comment: *Mathematica* will compute the moments exactly--and very rapidly, too.  I'm confident other computer algebra platforms could do this as well.